# Application failed unexpectedly Could not connect to amqp

Tags: wolkenkit

I'm using wolkenkit 1.2.0,
I'm starting wolkenkit this way:

```
wolkenkit start --shared-key 123456 --verbose
```

I'm sending commands and I can see them in the logs, but I'm not receiving events. Could it be related to the following error I'm seeing in the logs all the time:

```
Application failed unexpectedly. (fatal)
wolkenkit-flows::wolkenkit-flows@1.2.0::tailwind@1.0.1 
(/wolkenkit/node_modules/tailwind/lib/TailwindApp.js)
12:07:50.298@2018-01-14 5#0
{
  err: {
  name: 'Error',
  message: 'Could not connect to amqp://wolkenkit:123456@messagebus:5672.',
  stack: 'Error: Could not connect to amqp://wolkenkit:123456@messagebus:5672.
  at /wolkenkit/node_modules/hase/dist/hase.js:22:23
  at /wolkenkit/node_modules/amqplib/callback_api.js:16:10
  at Socket.<anonymous> (/wolkenkit/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connect.js:167:18)
  at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
  at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
  at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
  at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
  at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)'
 }
}
```

I've tried upgrading to 1.2.1 with no help.
I've deleted all the containers and started from the top. Still not working.

Edit:
Full Log of the basic chat app:

```
Failed to initialize application. (fatal)
wolkenkit-core::wolkenkit-core@1.2.0::tailwind@1.0.1 (/wolkenkit/node_modules/tailwind/lib/TailwindApp.js)
12:25:49.249@2018-01-14 5#0
{
  err: {
    name: 'Error',
    message: 'connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.4:5432',
    stack: 'Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.4:5432
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1182:14)'
  }
}
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Application failed unexpectedly. (fatal)
wolkenkit-core::wolkenkit-core@1.2.0::tailwind@1.0.1 (/wolkenkit/node_modules/tailwind/lib/TailwindApp.js)
12:25:52.226@2018-01-14 5#0
{
  err: {
    name: 'Error',
    message: 'Could not connect to amqp://wolkenkit:09a7458453d58c93d22a2b823bf2fccee3b704db@messagebus:5672.',
    stack: 'Error: Could not connect to amqp://wolkenkit:09a7458453d58c93d22a2b823bf2fccee3b704db@messagebus:5672.
    at /wolkenkit/node_modules/hase/dist/hase.js:22:23
    at /wolkenkit/node_modules/amqplib/callback_api.js:16:10
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/wolkenkit/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connect.js:167:18)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)'
  }
}
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Application failed unexpectedly. (fatal)
wolkenkit-core::wolkenkit-core@1.2.0::tailwind@1.0.1 (/wolkenkit/node_modules/tailwind/lib/TailwindApp.js)
12:25:54.858@2018-01-14 5#0
{
  err: {
    name: 'Error',
    message: 'Could not connect to amqp://wolkenkit:09a7458453d58c93d22a2b823bf2fccee3b704db@messagebus:5672.',
    stack: 'Error: Could not connect to amqp://wolkenkit:09a7458453d58c93d22a2b823bf2fccee3b704db@messagebus:5672.
    at /wolkenkit/node_modules/hase/dist/hase.js:22:23
    at /wolkenkit/node_modules/amqplib/callback_api.js:16:10
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/wolkenkit/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connect.js:167:18)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)'
  }
}
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Application failed unexpectedly. (fatal)
wolkenkit-core::wolkenkit-core@1.2.0::tailwind@1.0.1 (/wolkenkit/node_modules/tailwind/lib/TailwindApp.js)
12:25:58.737@2018-01-14 5#0
{
  err: {
    name: 'Error',
    message: 'Could not connect to amqp://wolkenkit:09a7458453d58c93d22a2b823bf2fccee3b704db@messagebus:5672.',
    stack: 'Error: Could not connect to amqp://wolkenkit:09a7458453d58c93d22a2b823bf2fccee3b704db@messagebus:5672.
    at /wolkenkit/node_modules/hase/dist/hase.js:22:23
    at /wolkenkit/node_modules/amqplib/callback_api.js:16:10
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/wolkenkit/node_modules/amqplib/lib/connect.js:167:18)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:315:30)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)'
  }
}
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Running application. (info)
wolkenkit-core::wolkenkit-core@1.2.0::tailwind@1.0.1 (/wolkenkit/node_modules/tailwind/lib/TailwindApp.js)
12:26:02.761@2018-01-14 5#0
```

Comment: Can you run the [wolkenkit-todomvc](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit-todomvc) sample application using your start command? I tried this on my machine, and everything worked perfectly. I would like to find out whether the problem is related to some setting on your machine, or whether it's application-specific. Which application do you try to run this way? Is it an official sample app, or a custom app?

Comment: Thank for helping! This is from running my app. I tried to test it using wolkenkit-console. I just tried to run the default chat app I created using wolkenkit init. It looks good and working from wolkenkit-console - I am able to send commands and see events - not able to send events is probably something wrong with my app. But I still get the error above in the chat app logs. Should I be concerned with the error if the app is running ok?

Comment: No, because this error is normal, at least when starting the application. The reason for this is that RabbitMQ takes way longer to start and become ready than the rest of the system, so some container complain about RabbitMQ not yet being ready. So a *few* of these messages in the beginning of the log is perfectly fine. Nevertheless, this brings us to the question what the problem with your specific application is… maybe let's discuss this in the [Slack channel](http://slackin.wolkenkit.io/). Once we have an answer, we can post it here.

Comment: Thank you, I understand. Sounds like this solves my issue. I've added the full log if it help further

Comment: Hm, I'm very sorry, but unfortunately it doesn't help :-( … let's see what we'll find out via Slack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, I think that this problem is specific to your application, not to wolkenkit in general.

In my opinion I think that you need to figure out which command or event causes your application to not work properly. Unfortunately, I can't help with that too much, without having a closer look at the application's code.

I'm very sorry that I don't have a better answer for you.

However, I hope this at least helps to point you into the right direction.

Comment: Thank you! I figured out the problem. It was my app. The error I get about connecting to RabbitMQ doesn't affect the server and everything works perfectly. Thanks!